# Multiple Async Operations with Delegates

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-4.0, delegates

**Code:**

```
private delegate void NotificationDelegate(sis_company company, int days, string type, string param);

private NotificationDelegate _notDel;

private void Notifications(sys_company company, int days, string type, string param)
{
    if (*something*)
    {
        _notDel = SendEmails;
        _notDel.BeginInvoke(company, days, type, param, CallBackNotification, null);
    }
}

private void SendEmails(sys_company company, int days, string type, string param)
{
    //Here I'll send all e-mails.
}

private void CallBackNotification(IAsyncResult r)
{
    if (this.IsDisposed) return;

    try
    {
        _notDel.EndInvoke(r);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogWriter.Log(ex, "EndInvoke Error");
    }
}
```

**Expected Behaviour:**

The `Notifications` method is called whenever a company meets the deadline. During the initialization a method loops for each company and calls `Notifications` inside that loop.

**Problem:**

As you can see, `_notDel` is a global variable, used later on to `EndInvoke` the `delegate`. The problem is that after the second `Notifications` call, the object is not the same anymore, giving me the error that says:

"*The IAsyncResult object provided does not match this delegate*."

Comment: Why is `_notDel` global? Can you make it per instance? You have to encapsulate each delegate instance for this to work

Comment: You simply need a transient object which holds the delegate as a field which is passed as a state parameter for later use.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov How can I `EndInvoke` inside the `CallBackNotification`?

Comment: Show us the declaration of the class

Comment: Just pass your _notDel as the last parameter for BeginInvoke and use r.AsyncState to get the source delegate then

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov This is inside the Main form.

Comment: @AlexK I'll try that right now.

Comment: @AlexK It works, thanks. You can add as the answer of this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass your `notDel` as the last parameter for BeginInvoke and use `r.AsyncState` to get the source delegate then.

```
//Call like this:

NotificationDelegate notDel = Notifications;
notDel.BeginInvoke(company, days, type, param, CallBackNotification, notDel);

//And inside the CallBack:

var del = r.AsyncState as NotificationDelegate;

if (del != null)
    del.EndInvoke(r);
```